# Display a full length div/span below td of a tr

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I have a table with 2 column, Name, Type. The error message comes up as a div in columns 1. I would like to extract that div and display it as a full td below the tr. I tried doing this:

```
$('#file-preview-thumbnails').find('tr').filter(":not(:hidden)").each(function () {
                var $progressBar = $(this).find('td.file-details-cell').find('.file-thumb-progress.kv-hidden');
                if($progressBar.length) {
                    $('<tr><td colspan="3>' + $progressBar[0].outerHTML + '</td></tr>').insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));
                }
            });
```

But the issue here is, as there is `td` and `tr` padding added, this shows up as a separate tr on UI. Is there a way I can show the div like this :

[image]

The table is built via plugin.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#input-b6").fileinput({
                theme: "explorer",
                dropZoneEnabled: true,
                maxFileCount: 10,
                msgUploadError: 'Unable to add file(s) to the case.',
                showDrag: false,
                showUploadedThumbs: true,
                hideThumbnailContent: true,
                browseClass: "btn btn-primary buttonCss",
                uploadClass: "btn btn-primary buttonCss",
                removeClass: "btn btn-primary buttonCss",
                removeErrorClass: 'btn btn-primary buttonCss',
                showCaption: false,
                initialPreviewAsData: true,
                uploadUrl: 'null',
                removeLabel: 'Remove Files',
                uploadLabel: 'Upload Files',
                browseLabel: 'Attach Files',
                uploadAsync: true,
                elPreviewContainer: '#banner_default',
                elPreviewImage: '#file-preview-thumbnails',
                msgSizeTooLarge: "This file is larger than {size} MB",
                layoutTemplates: {
                    main2: '{preview}\n<div class="kv-upload-progress hide"></div>\n' +
                        '  <div class="input-group-btn">\n' +
                        '{browse}\n{upload}\n{remove}\n',
                    actionDelete: '<button type="button" class="kv-file-remove {removeClass} removeBtnCss" title="{removeTitle}"{dataUrl}{dataKey}>{removeIcon}</button>\n',
                    actions: '<div class="file-actions">\n' +
                        '<div class="file-footer-buttons">\n' +
                        '<div class="dropdown">\n' +
                        '<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">\n' +
                        '<span class="caret"></span></button>\n' +
                        '<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">\n' +
                        '<li><a href="#">{upload} Upload</a></li>\n' +
                        '<li><a href="#">{delete} Remove</a></li>\n' +
                        '<li><a href="#">{zoom} Preview</a></li>\n' +
                        '</ul>\n' +
                        '</div>\n' +
                        '</div>',
                    actionZoom: '<button type="button" class="{zoomClass}" title="{zoomTitle}" onclick="openNewWindow(event)">{zoomIcon}</button>',
                },
            });
            
            
            var dropZoneHtml = $('.file-drop-zone-title');


            var typeOptionSelect = '<select class="form-control" id="idReportType">\n' +
                '<option value="" disabled selected>Select Type</option>\n' +
                '<option value="Appeal Document">Appeal Document</option>\n' +
                '<option value="Police Report">Police Report</option>\n' +
                '<option value="Travel Itinerary">Travel Itinerary</option>\n' +
                '<option value="Accums Spreadsheet">Accums Spreadsheet</option>\n' +
                '<option value="Clinical Document">Clinical Document</option>\n' +
                '<option value="Other">Other</option>\n' +
                '</select>';
                
                $('#input-b6').on('filebatchselected', function (event, files) {
                var dropTableZone = $('#file-preview-thumbnails');
                dropTableZone.removeClass('panel').addClass('panel');
                if (!dropTableZone.find('th').length) {
                    var dataToBePushed = [];
                    dataToBePushed.push(["NAME", "TYPE"]);
                    //Create a HTML Table element.
                    var table = $("<table />");
                    table[0].border = "1";

                    //Get the count of columns.
                    var columnCount = dataToBePushed[0].length;
                    //Add the header row.
                    var row = $(table[0].insertRow(-1));
                    for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                        var headerCell = $("<th scope=\"col\"/>");
                        headerCell.html(dataToBePushed[0][i]);
                        row.append(headerCell);
                    }

                    row.insertBefore('div > tr:first');
                }

                dropTableZone.find('tr').filter(":not(:hidden)").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).find('td.file-actions-cell').prev().find('select').length === 0) {
                        $('<td>' + typeOptionSelect + '</td>').insertBefore($(this).find('td.file-actions-cell'));
                    }
                });
                $('.file-drop-zone').empty().append(dropZoneHtml);
                dropTableZone.insertBefore($('.input-group-btn'));


            });
})
```

```css
.file-input.theme-explorer {
            padding: 1rem;
        }

        .has-error .form-control {
            border-color: #00000038 !important;
        }

        .theme-explorer .file-thumb-progress .progress, .theme-explorer .file-thumb-progress .progress-bar {
            height: 26px;
            font-size: 11px;
            line-height: 26px;
        }

        .btn.btn-primary.buttonCss {
            width: 32%;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .removeBtnCss .glyphicon.glyphicon-trash {
            color: #b11313d9 !important;
        }

        #file-preview-thumbnails {
            margin-bottom: 1rem;
            padding: 1rem;
        }

        samp {
            display: none;
        }

        .input-group-btn {
            width: 100% !important;
            display: flex !important;
            justify-content: space-between !important;
        }

        body {
            max-width: 100%;
        }


        #dropdownMenuButton {
            background-color: white !important;
            border: 0.5px solid #00000038 !important;
        }

        th {
            width: 60rem;
        }

        td {
            padding-top: .5em;
            padding-bottom: .5em;
        }

        .file-upload-indicator {
            display: none !important;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.3/css/fileinput.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.3/themes/explorer/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.3/js/fileinput.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/5.0.3/themes/explorer/theme.js"></script>

<div class="file-loading">
                    <input id="input-b6" name="input-b6[]" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
                </div>
                <div id="banner_default"></div>
                <div id="file-preview-thumbnails" class="panel-default">
                </div>
```

Comment: I am very confused. So you are having a div and you are trying to trigger some JS to transform the content of the div into a table cell? Can you provide the full HTML before and after the transformation? Otherwise it's impossible to tell what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have edited my header statement, sorry for the confusion. I would like to display a div below a table row.

Comment: can you post your HTML to question?

Comment: This is a plugin, so I have inserted a running code snippet in my question. Just try to attach a file and click upload. The progress bar will show up, I need that progress bar as shown in the 2nd image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in your generated HTML, a missing quote after `colspan`. With the quote fixed, the error div takes up the whole row, as expected. I also added a line to hide the existing progress bar, so that you don't end up with two.

```
$('#file-preview-thumbnails').find('tr').filter(":not(:hidden)").each(function () {
                var $progressBar = $(this).find('td.file-details-cell').find('.file-thumb-progress.kv-hidden');
                if($progressBar.length) {
                    $('<tr><td colspan="3">' + $progressBar[0].outerHTML + '</td></tr>').insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));
                    $progressBar.hide()
                }
            });
```

Result:
[image]

---

EDIT: CSS changes to make it look like in your picture:

```
.theme-explorer .file-thumb-progress .progress {
  margin: 0 -10;
}
.theme-explorer .file-thumb-progress .progress, .theme-explorer .file-thumb-progress .progress-bar {
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

Apply those after the given CSS or use `!important` after every instruction to get this:

[image]

Comment: The issue here is the td and tr has css globally with padding as 1 rem, which makes it looks as if its a different tr. Can I reduce the space between the above `tr` and the `tr` whcih I added.\

Comment: @NagendraSingh CSS added